# Сократить уже существующий метод

Tags: android, kotlin

Можно ли объеденить всё в одну проверку?

```
 pass.textView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            if (editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) validatePassword()
            else pass.setValid()
        }
    })

    name.textView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (s!!.isNotEmpty()) isNameValid()
            else name.setValid()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать **класс-адаптер** для сокращения лишнего кода.

Выглядит это так:

```
public class zTextWatcher : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {}
}
```

Используется так:

```
pass.textView.addTextChangedListener(object : zTextWatcher()  {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        if (editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) validatePassword()
        else pass.setValid()
    }
})

name.textView.addTextChangedListener(object : zTextWatcher()  {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        if (editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) isNameValid()
        else name.setValid()
    }
})
```

### UPD

Вариант при имплемениации `TextWatcher'a`:

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    View focus = getCurrentFocus()
    if (focus != null) {
        switch (focus.getId()) {
            case /*кейс для name*/:
                if (editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) isNameValid()
                else name.setValid()
                break
            case /*кейс для pass*/:
                if (editable.toString().isNotEmpty()) validatePassword()
                else pass.setValid()
                break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в моем случае textView?

Comment: @Inkognito, да, в вашем случае заместо `text` используйте `pass.textView` и `name.textView`

Comment: когда использую zTextWatcher в классе пишет мол он должен быть проинициализирован так как имеет конструктор.и предлагает заменить конструктор invocation или сделать класс open, но не помогает

Comment: @Inkognito можно попробовать объявить класс абстрактным, но это может не помочь

Comment: а почему вы не хотите просто унаследовать класс от TextWatcher ? заIMPLEMENTите методы и попробуете в них работать с EditText'ами?

Comment: @Inkognito попробуйте использовать         `name.textView.addTextChangedListener(this)`

Comment: @zTrap мне интересно как Вы будете обращаться к тому или иному EditText? в параметрах то его нет

Comment: @Inkognito нашёл ошибку, исправил (уж простите, на `kotlin'e` полноценно ещё не писал). Обновил ответ

Comment: @zTrap что то типо если курсор на name, тогда то то ? если курсор на пароле тогда то то ?)

Comment: @Morozov вы про анонимные классы слышали? Классы-обёртки (адаптеры)?

Comment: @Morozov в данном случае я предложил обернуть `TextWatcher` чтобы не видеть ненужных и пустых методов

Comment: @zTrap да я согласен, я просто вместе с Вами думаю как быть с editText'ами?)

Comment: @Morozov эмммм.. сейчас дополню ответ прямым использованием, если абстрактное сложно для вашего понимания

Comment: @Morozov this разрешило ситуацию, спасибо.

Comment: @zTrap у меня немного видоизменился код, в том плане что я унаследовал класс, переопределил методы и далее использовал name.textView.addTextChangedListener(this), пока без ошибок. Теперь по идее мне нужно для в самих методах играться для каждого из editText'ов? ну в зависимости от того который использую?

Comment: @Inkognito при вашей реализации вам не получится отличить изменение текста в `pass` от изменения в `name`

Comment: @Inkognito дополнил ответ